# Read big files to GCP with Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking for a solution how to read multiple files from FTP to Google CloudStorage in an efficient way. Each file size is 3-5 GB, the amount of files is 100-200.

I found the next solutions: read files using GAE instance.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Maybe examine Google's own Storage Transfer Service ... see:

https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/

While this doesn't use FTP as a source, it seems that one could either run an HTTP server on the FTP server machine (if you have access) or FTP download the 1TB of data to a machine which does have an HTTP server.  If it is one time, consider using a transfer appliance:

https://cloud.google.com/transfer-appliance/

See also:

https://cloud.google.com/products/data-transfer/

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to use Google Cloud [parallel uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads) to Cloud Storage using `gsutil compose`. You can try this with:

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp bigfile gs://your-bucket
```

Basically:

1. gsutil is dividing the file in multiple smaller chuncks.
2. It then uploads all the files to Cloud Storage.
3. They get composed as a single file
4. Then it deletes all the smaller chuncks

Keep in mind this has a trade off described in the docs:

> Using parallel composite uploads presents a tradeoff between upload
>   performance and download configuration: If you enable parallel
>   composite uploads your uploads will run faster, but someone will need
>   to install a compiled crcmod on every machine
>   where objects are downloaded by gsutil or other Python applications.
>   Note that for such uploads, crcmod is required for downloading
>   regardless of whether the parallel composite upload option is on or
>   not. For some distributions this is easy (e.g., it comes pre-installed
>   on macOS), but in other cases some users have found it difficult.

In case you are not able to use `gsutil` and you can't install the Cloud Storage SDK in your FTP server, you could download the files in a VM and run the Cloud Storage SDK or gsutil in this VM.

App Engine Standard does not allow to write to disk. Thus, any file you upload is going to be stored on [memory](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/) until you upload them to Cloud Storage. So I don't think this is convenient in this case.

App Engine Flexible does allow writing to disk. This is an [ephemeral](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features) disk, once it get's restarted the contents of the disk get's deleted and each week is restarted. But you wouldn't be taking advantaged of the Load Balancer and the Automatic Scaling the instance has.

In this case, I think the best way would be a [Google Cloud preemptible](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) VM. Now, even though this VM only lives for one day at max, they run at a lower price than a normal VM. Once they are going to [get terminated](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance#handle_preemption), you could check which files had been uploaded to Storage and resume your workload in a new preemptible VM. You could also use a large number of this VMs working in parallel to speed up the download and upload process.

Comment: It's a good idea, but if I follow your advice it will be needed to have a `gcloud` on FTP machine, as well as to provide the keys to that machine. What if FTP machine is not mine (a different cloud/service) and I have only credentials to FTP? Simply saying I can't run `gsutil`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated my answer with more information that can be helpful.

Comment: Interesting! In your example you're creating an instance within GCP, but I'm talking about something different. What if FTP is a third-party service and the only thing I can do is to download a file from there. I can't create a VM on their side.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have explained myself wrongly. The VM is in Google Cloud.  The VM is just for downloading the files and be able to install `gsutil` and use the parallel upload option. You could also install the Cloud Storage SDK and use it to automate the process. Also, there may be a connection from your third party FTP server to connect directly to Cloud Storage. You can see @Kolban comment on this matter.